# Change list-view item background dynamically

Tags: android, list, listview, cursor, background-color

I am having a list of songs and want to highlight(change background of) that song which is currently playing.It should be able to change background when my song finishes and goes to next one.I also want background to change when I select any list-view item.
Can somebody please guide me on how to move forward with this.
Code:-

I am implmenting this code but more than one list-item color is changing

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.bindView(view, context, cursor);

    final View vi=inflater.inflate(layout, null, false);
    TextView titleS=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.TitleSong);
    TextView artistS=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.Artist);
    int Title_index;
    int Artist_index;



        Title_index=cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
        Artist_index=cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
        titleS.setText(cursor.getString(Title_index));
        artistS.setText(cursor.getString(Artist_index));

     if(cursor.getPosition()==MainActivity.songPosition){
         titleS.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
     }

}
```

Comment: See if adding an `else` statement to go with the `if` helps. Add `else { titleS.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE); }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to have a a field with the current song index in your adapter and depending on that index chose a background. Then when the song stops playing you probably have some kind of callback, so there you can increase this index and invoke `notifyDataSetChange()` on your adapter to redraw your views.

And the last thing, when you select a list item, you should change current song index to the index of the selected item and also call `notifyDataSetChange()`.

Here is some code

```
getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //initialize view

    if (position == currentSongPosition) {
        yourView.setBackground(...);
    }

    yourView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(View view) {
              currentSongPosition = position;
              notifyDataSetChange();
          }
    });

}
```

Comment: How should I implement adapter?I mean change background on what basis?
I can't do it using onClick method

Comment: I wrote some code up there. And actually you can do that onClick

Comment: As I am using CUrsorAdapter so I should be using it instead in bindView method?

Comment: Hey check my updated question,multiple item's background are changing

Comment: As @vikram wrote, add `else {itleS.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE); }` clause with your initial color.

Comment: I also want to change color on pause so for that should I use tag?

Comment: Hey it is working on a single activity perfectly but when I am using it inside tab activity then its showing me multiple background changes  and also only changes once I scroll my list.

Comment: Well, it's hard to tell anything without the code posted, so I suggest you to post one more question with some code included.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17732144/list-item-change-background-on-click
Check this link